# Probability of no adjacent and identical items in a sequence (with replacement)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, markov-chains

Let $\{a_1,a_2,\dots, a_n\}$ be a set of items where $P(a_i)=p_i$ denotes the probability that item $i\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ is picked in the set where we use $\textit{with replacement}$. What is the probability that there exists no adjacent and identical items in a generated sequence of length $L$. To understand what I mean, lets say we have $n=2$ and $L=3$, then all ($2^3$) combinations is
$$a_1 a_1 a_1,\ a_1a_1a_2,\ a_1a_2a_1,\ a_1a_2a_2,\ a_2a_1a_1,\ a_2a_1a_2,\ a_2a_2a_1,\ a_2a_2a_2.$$
The only two sequence that does not contain adjacent and identical items is $a_1a_2a_1$ and $a_2a_1a_2$. If the probabilities is uniformed, i.e $P(a_i)=1/2$, then the probability of not generating a sequence of adjacent numbers is $\frac{2}{8}$. For any $n$ and $L$, and uniformed probabilities $P(a_i)=\frac{1}{n}$, then the general formula would be
$$\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{L-1}.$$
However if the probabilities is not uniformed, how can I calculate this probability without calculating all cases separately, i.e is there a formula? Maybe you can solve this using a Markov chain?

I tried to see the pattern using $n=2,L=3$ and the probabilities $P(a_1)=\frac{2}{3}$ and $P(a_2)=\frac{1}{3}$. The only sequences containing no adjacent and identical item is $a_1a_2a_1$ and $a_2a_1a_2$ as before. The probability of the first sequence is
$\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{2}{3}=\frac{4}{27}$
and the probability of the second one is
$\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{3}=\frac{2}{27}$
so that the probability of generating a sequence with no identical and adjacent item is
$$\frac{4}{27}+\frac{2}{27}=\frac{2}{9}.$$
So how do I get the general formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight modification of Markov chains works for this problem. Let $p_{i,j}$ denote the probability that a randomly generated length-$j$ string has no pair and ends in $a_i$. It is easy to see that $p_{i,1}=p_i$ and $p_{i,j+1}=p_i\sum_{i'\ne i}p_{i',j}$, so
$$\begin{bmatrix}p_{1,L}\\p_{2,L}\\\vdots\\p_{n,L}\end{bmatrix}=A^{L-1}\begin{bmatrix}p_1\\p_2\\\vdots\\p_n\end{bmatrix}$$
where row $i$ of $A$ is all $p_i$'s except the diagonal entry which is $0$. Then the desired probability is just the sum of entries of the resulting vector.

Comment: The only reason that I don't (also) upvote your answer, is that I am totally ignorant of Markov Chains.  Therefore, I am not qualified to have an opinion on whether your approach is valid, or even what your approach means.  I can't upvote an answer that I don't understand.